# Glide: How to stop glide from loading images from cache instead load from server each time

Tags: java, android, json, android-glide

I tried everything possible but couldn't try to figure out how to update images to glide whenever my json is updated

MY android app initally loads images from json using glide for firsttime after that it only load images from cache.It doesnot load images that are updated on server till i delete the app and reinstall it

I tried using **diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)** and **.skipMemoryCache(true)** but nothing happened

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getMedium())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
```

This is my code GalleryAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import java.util.List;

import com.bumptech.glide.signature.StringSignature;
import com.dailysolutions.sn.R;
import com.dailysolutions.sn.model.Image;

/**
 * Created by Sagunesh on 31/03/16.
 */

public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Image> images;
    private Context mContext;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView thumbnail;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
    }


    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<Image> images) {
        mContext = context;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.gallery_thumbnail, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Image image = images.get(position);

        Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getMedium())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(holder.thumbnail);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private GalleryAdapter.ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final GalleryAdapter.ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.dailysolutions.sn.R;
import com.dailysolutions.sn.adapter.GalleryAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.dailysolutions.sn.app.AppController;
import com.dailysolutions.sn.model.Image;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;



    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String endpoint = "https://www.freesabkuch.com/api_mehndi/glide.json";
    private ArrayList<Image> images;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private GalleryAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AdView mAdView;
    InterstitialAd interstitial;

    // Our created menu to use
    private Menu mymenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        initNavigationDrawer();
        checkConnectivity();

        //advertisement
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
// Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
// Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), images);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new GalleryAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new GalleryAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("images", images);
                bundle.putInt("position", position);

                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                SlideshowDialogFragment newFragment = SlideshowDialogFragment.newInstance();
                newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                newFragment.show(ft, "slideshow");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        fetchImages();




    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
// If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // Start or resume the game.
        super.onResume();
        displayInterstitial();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        displayInterstitial();
    }
    private void fetchImages() {

        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading....");
        pDialog.show();

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(endpoint,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        pDialog.hide();

                        images.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Image image = new Image();
                                image.setName(object.getString("name"));

                                JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("url");
                                image.setSmall(url.getString("small"));
                                image.setMedium(url.getString("medium"));
                                image.setLarge(url.getString("large"));
                                image.setTimestamp(object.getString("timestamp"));

                                images.add(image);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        exit();
    }


    public void initNavigationDrawer() {

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                int id = menuItem.getItemId();

                switch (id){
                    case R.id.home:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.share:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Share",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        try {
                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            i.setType("text/plain");
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
                            String sAux = "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
                            sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Orion.Soft \n\n";
                            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose one"));
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            //e.toString();
                        }
                    case R.id.trash:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Drawer Closed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.logout:
                       exit();

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView tv_email = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_email.setText("Daily Solutions");
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
                super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    private void checkConnectivity(){
        if(ConnectionHelper.isConnectedOrConnecting(getApplicationContext())) {
            hideErrorsBar(true);

        }else {
            //hideErrorsBar(false);
            Intent Intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NoInternet.class);
            startActivity(Intent);
            finish();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Add our menu
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // We should save our menu so we can use it to reset our updater.
        mymenu = menu;

        //
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                // Do animation start
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.iv_refresh, null);
                Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_refresh);
                rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                iv.startAnimation(rotation);
                item.setActionView(iv);
                new UpdateTask(this).execute();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void resetUpdating()
    {
        // Get our refresh item from the menu
        MenuItem m = mymenu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
        if(m.getActionView()!=null)
        {
            // Remove the animation.
            m.getActionView().clearAnimation();
            m.setActionView(null);
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well everyone thanks a lot for help :)

I resolved this problem by disabling cache of volley library that was causing the issue but anyway thanks for help :)

```
//disabling caching for url
        AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Signature` for invalidating cache and load image from network. Try

```
Glide.with(Fragment/context)
.load(imagePath)
.signature(new StringSignature(yourVersion))
.into(ImageView);
```

Just pass `new StringSignature(System.currentTimeMillis()+"")` to the signature so that it will load the image from network every time

Comment: Hey thanks for the help I tried that but nothing happened can u make a change in my galleryadapter.java file  `Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getMedium())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .signature(new StringSignature(System.currentTimeMillis()+""))
                .into(holder.thumbnail);`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setting `Signatures`
As per the glide documentation on caching

Try this

```
    Glide.with(context)
   .load(url) .
    signature(new StringSignature(System.currentTimeMillis()))
 .into(imageView);
```

Check [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation) for more details

Comment: hey thanks for help i tried that but nothing happened can u make change in my above file **GalleryAdapter.java** and give the ans because i think i am doing something wrong   This i did `Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getMedium())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .signature(new StringSignature(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .into(holder.thumbnail);`